# Covariance between X and ln(Y) with X and Y beta random variables

Tags: data-transformation, covariance, beta-distribution, dirichlet-distribution

I have a Dirichlet distribution $D(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3)$, with $\alpha=\sum_{i=1}^3 \alpha_i$. I know that the marginal distributions are beta distributions. Consider for instance the first 2 marginal random variables: $X \sim B(\alpha_1,\alpha-\alpha_1)$ and $Y \sim B(\alpha_2,\alpha-\alpha_2)$.

My question is how to compute $\textrm{cov}(X,\ln(Y))$ ? Can an exact expression be found (preferable), or do I need to use an approximation somewhere (perhaps working with a Taylor expansion)?

I know that $\textrm{cov}(X,Y)=\frac{-\alpha_1 \alpha_2}{\alpha^2(\alpha+1)}$.

I also know that: $\textrm{cov}(X,\ln(Y)) = E[X\ln(Y)]-E[X]E[\ln(Y)]$. Starting from this formula, the difficulty seems to be obtaining an expression for $E[X\ln(Y)]$.

Comment: Not that it helps with your question, but the order of terms in the covariance is wrong.

Comment: In order to be able to compute that expected value you NEED to know the joint PDF of X and Y. Unless they are independet the knowledge of the marginals does not help you, because same marginals can lead to different joints.

Comment: Can that joint pdf somehow be derived from the fact that both X and Y originate from the Dirichlet distribution?

Comment: Yes: the Dirichlet distribution provides the full (multivariate) probability law.  I doubt you will find an analytically tractable expression for the covariance of $X$ and $\log(Y)$, though.